# parent.document.getElementById("...") is null or not an object in IE7

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-7, null, parent-child

I have done some research, but as a JavaScript novice, I can't seem to get anything to work for my specific case:

I have an iframe in a page, and in that iframe's document, I have the following code:

```
function fun(){
var slideTitle = api.getField('title');
    parent.document.getElementById("slidecaptionOoH").innerHTML = slideTitle;
```

In the parent document I have: 
    `<h4 id="slidecaptionOoH"></h4>`

I've tried putting a comment in between the  tags, but I still get the error in IE7. The page displays fine, but obviously I don't want people to see the error.

---

Well, I think I've narrowed down the problem a bit. I think it may have to do with the iframe document's function executing before the parent is finished loading. I'm using the treesaver.js framework in the parent, which involves heavy DOM manipulation. When I turn off treesaver, I no longer receive the error.

So I guess my question now is, how do I delay the function until the parent is finished loading? Or delay the loading of the iframe document altogether?

Comment: have you tried parentNode instead of parent?

Comment: @amosrivera — `window.parent` is the parent frame. `window.parentNode` doesn't exist unless you create it.

Comment: I just tried it and it results in 'parenNode' is undefined.

Comment: Are the pages on the same domain, port and protocol?

Comment: @Quentin — I've tried window.parent and top.parent, and I still get the "null or not an object" error.

Comment: @mplungjan — You've just thickened the plot. The pages are on the same domain, and I can only assume the same port and protocol. Interestingly though, I just discovered that I get the error consistently when working in a local environment, but intermittently when it's live on the server. And in most of those cases, it gives an error without specifying it.

Comment: `parent` and `window.parent` are the same thing. If the document is only one frame deep, then `top` and `parent` are also the same thing (and thus so are `top.parent` and `parent`).

Answer (score 3):

You can keep pooling the parent until it has loaded the respective child with:

```
function fun(){
    var slideTitle = api.getField('title');
    var el = parent.document.getElementById("slidecaptionOoH");
    if (el){
        el.innerHTML = slideTitle;
    } else{
        setTimeout(fun, 50);
    }
    el = null;
}
```

But this is just a(dirt) work around.

Comment: Well, it seems that I must have narrowed down prematurely. Before you posted this, I tried to use setTimeout to delay the entire function. Even at 10 seconds, I still get the error. It's weird. As I said, it doesn't happen all the time either...Oh well. Thanks.