# "getElementById(...).options is null or not an object" in IE7 only

Tags: javascript, select, internet-explorer-7, null, getelementbyid

I am coming to ask my question in a sorry state of defeat. I'm nearly up to 10 hours spent on this single sorry little problem, and have spent many of them digging through similar issues here on stackoverflow as well as elsewhere on the internet.

Here's the deal: I'm using a select form with option values to complete links to pages, but when I use onchange (or onblur) to get at the selected element, IE7 thinks there's nothing there (though IE8, 9, Chrome, FF function as I intended).

The CMS is convoluted so there are some limitations to where I can add scripts, but I do realize DOM could be an issue for me here. I've also tried putting the function inside window.onload in case that was causing the problem, but that doesn't appear to be it. Here's my code:

```
<form name="myBrowseForm" action="/portal/" method="post">
    <label for="redirect">Choose a Region</label>
    <br />
    <select id="organization" onchange="document.myBrowseForm.action=document.getElementById('organization').options[document.getElementById('organization').selectedIndex].value;" name="shortcut">
        <option value="#">Select a Region</option>
        <option value="/r1">New England (1)</option>
        <option value="/r2">Northeast & Caribbean (2)</option>
        </select>
        <input border="0" hspace="5" src="/btn_go.gif" alt="Go" onclick="if(document.myBrowseForm.action != ''){document.myBrowseForm.submit();} else return false;" type="image">
        </form>
```

I appreciate any guidance you may have for me!

Comment: One things that older versions of IEs javascript engine enforces but alot of others dont is unique element IDs. Can you double check your element ID is unique on the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147556/javascript-getelementbyid-is-null-or-not-an-object-ie and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839423/parent-document-getelementbyid-is-null-or-not-an-object-in-ie7

Comment: the <6% of users whom aren't intelligent enough to upgrade their browser probably aren't savvy enough to use a cms. my 2 cents.

Comment: The way you are doing this seems correct...are you sure you don't have any other elements with an ID of 'organization'? Also, with inline javascript, you can just use `this` instead of `document.getElementById('organization')`.

Comment: Why are you doing `document.getElementById('organization')` in an inline event handler for that very same element? Just use `this`.

Comment: Good thought about the unique ID, as having such a runaway CMS has presented triplicate ids before, but that did not wind up being the case here! 

Sadly that <6% makes up 100% of my users, and they're not allowed to upgrade.

Thanks for the `this` tips! In my degubbing frenzy I just wanted to make absolutely sure that the right element was being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try something like this:

```
<form name="myBrowseForm" action="/portal/" method="post">
    <label for="redirect">Choose a Region</label>
    <br />
    <select id="organization" onchange="document.myBrowseForm.action=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" name="shortcut">
        <option value="#">Select a Region</option>
        <option value="/r1">New England (1)</option>
        <option value="/r2">Northeast & Caribbean (2)</option>
    </select>
    <input border="0" hspace="5" src="/btn_go.gif" alt="Go" onclick="if(document.myBrowseForm.action != ''){document.myBrowseForm.submit();} else return false;" type="image">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `document.getElementById('organization').value` rather than options?

Giving:

```
<form name="myBrowseForm" action="/portal/" method="post">
    <label for="redirect">Choose a Region</label>
    <br />
    <select id="organization" onchange="document.myBrowseForm.action=document.getElementById('organization').value;" name="shortcut">
        <option value="#">Select a Region</option>
        <option value="/r1">New England (1)</option>
        <option value="/r2">Northeast & Caribbean (2)</option>
    </select>
    <input border="0" hspace="5" src="/btn_go.gif" alt="Go" onclick="if(document.myBrowseForm.action != ''){document.myBrowseForm.submit();} else return false;" type="image">
</form>
```